# Why do I measure high and low voltage on a shop panel circuit?

Tags: voltage

I have power running to my shop, shop panel has a 100 amp main breaker, voltage on one leg reads 109 volts. The other shows less than 100 volts. If I turn 1 20 amp breaker on in the panel I then read 245 volts on one leg and 1volt on the other leg, as well as on the 20 amp breaker. I am far from an electrician so I'm at a total loss as to what my issue is and how to fix it. Service comes from a double pole 60 amp breaker from the house. Any advice would be appreciated.  Was like this when bought the house a yr ago, and was working fine(it seems) until last week. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you lost your feeder neutral.  Power down, then remove, clean and reinstall the neutral connections at both ends.  If it's never worked, then tell us everything you can about how neutral and safety ground wires are terminated at both ends.

Comment: That's what confuses me it has worked since we bought the home about a yr ago but last week the lights dimmed and went out . Now nothing

Comment: Which means that you either had a lose connection that finally fell apart, or something (weather, vibration, rodents) caused a problem with the neutral that didn't exist before. Stuff happens.

Comment: Gotcha, so definitely need to check both connections for the neutral,

Comment: Could be a loose or broken connection on the utility company wires.

Comment: It comes from the house to the shop via s junction

Comment: As others state, you've lost the neutral connection. The break could be at the house service entrance, at the power companies transformer, or elsewhere. **This is a serious hazard and can lead to damage to electrical devices, fire or electrocution.**  Unplug all appliances that you can, and get this fixed quickly. BTW, this issue happened at my house when a tree branch fell on the cable, and we were lucky to only lose a few appliances.

Comment: I have the breaker from the house to the shop off as well as all breakers in the shop panel. Double checked with multimeter just to be sure. So it's isolated.

Comment: @JoeJackson -- turn all the breakers in the shop and the shop breaker off, then turn all the breakers for the house except for the main and a single 240V circuit with nothing plugged into it off, then turn one single pole, presumably 15A or 20A breaker in the house on and measure the voltages at that 240V plug; do you still get pronounced shift in voltage between the two legs?

Comment: I will have to try that tomorrow morning when I get off work.  I'll update you

Comment: I assumed if you were having the exact same problem *in the house too*, you would have mentioned that.  Anyway I would not expect it to be so extreme if the entire house was affected, as the ground rods dampen the effect *somewhat*.  The garage doesn't have that dampening, *and should not*, because neutral and ground should be separate wires on the house feeder.

Comment: Not happening to the hone just the shop. We have an outside panel at the house that carries breaker for the a/c units and a cpl other 220 . And from one 60 amp double comes out of the panel to a junction box where the 3 wires attach and run to the shop

Comment: Wait. Did you say *three wires*?  Was this installed prior to 2008?

Comment: @harper yes I was informed the 3 wire set up was done in the mid 90s

Answer (score 5):

### Watch your tail!  The grounds in the shop will be energized!

This. This is why 3-wire feeders were outlawed in NEC 2008.

Anytime a neutral wire breaks, it is pulled up to the voltage of a hot wire.  In a 3-wire installation, it's also pulling **safety grounds** up to hot voltage, because neutral and ground are bonded in the subpanel.

The only thing that tries to bring this back to earth is the *grounding rods*, but based on the voltages you measured I suspect some short cutter didn't bother with those.   Well, if you get between anything 'grounded' (HA!) and the actual ground, *you become the ground rod*, an experience that will kill you.

Even if the ground rods were intact, dirt isn't a great conductor (that's why we bother to mine copper and aluminum).  So your loads will often *win* that tug-of-war and energize your grounds anyway.  This is why a 4-wire feeder is a Code requirement now.

### A neutral wire connection went bad

Wire problems are *almost always* at the ends of the wire, i.e. the terminal or at least inside that junction box.  People often "psych themselves out" into believing wire damage must surely be along the wire in an inaccessible location, thus unfixable. Usually untrue.

*That said, I won't discourage you from replacing a 3-wire feeder with 2-2-2-4 aluminum.  That will give you 90A instead of the 55 or 65A you have now, won't be costly, and most important, will give you separated neutral and ground! Aluminum is fine at these large wire sizes, the lugs are aluminum anyway.*

So go to each of the endpoints of the neutral wire - the main panel, the subpanel, and any intermediate splice boxes.  Power down the circuit, undo the connection completely, clean the wires, inspect everything, reapply No-alox "goop" if either wire or lug is aluminum,  and reinstall and torque the connections to specification.

Torque matters; and science recently showed it matters on small connections also!  Torque screwdrivers are very nice but overpriced, but beam-type 1/4" drive torque wrenches are "0-100 inch-pound" range, affordable, and never need recalibration. Amazon even has a $20 one that fits in the palm of your hand (though it makes you convert from in-lb to n-m).

Comment: I tried tightening a slotted bus rail screw in my box with an inch-pound, 1/4" drive ratchet. Couldn't keep it pushed in hard enough to get to the click before the screw head stripped out. A torque screwdriver is on my Christmas list. Don't know if it'll make a difference, but it'll make me feel cool.

Comment: Ok I turned power off at the panel from the home where it feeds the shop, I opened the panel and discovered the neutral wire had corroded from the point the wires split and was still attached and the wire had fallen. I cleaned it good and reattached it. Everything working correctly again. Thank you everyone for the help.